# How to change an XAML glyph from C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, glyph

I have an XAML label that shows an empty box. It's using a glyph font-family similar to [Microsoft's MDL2 assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) (except cross-platform).

```
<Label Content="&#xE739;" FontFamily="avares://HomeworkCalendar/Assets/Fonts#Symbols" PointerEnter="Check_OnPointerEnter" PointerLeave="Check_OnPointerLeave"/>
```

When the user hovers over the element I change it from a box to a checkbox.

```
private void Check_OnPointerEnter(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e) {
    var label = (Label)sender!;
    label.Content = "&#xE73A"; // Checked checkbox
}

private void Check_OnPointerLeave(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e) {
    var label = (Label)sender!;
    label.Content = "&#xE739"; // Unchecked checkbox
}
```

At program launch it displays the unchecked checkbox but the code-behind changes it to just the text `&#xE73A` and not a glyph. *I know why this is* but I can't find anywhere how to parse it differently so it shows up correctly. Anyone know how I can have it parse correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `&#x` is used in XAML to denote that the next four characters of a string literal are a hex code, `\x` is used in C#.

XAML: `&#xE739`

C#: `\xE739`

Answer (score 0):

On my WinUI3 SDK 1.1.0 I used `"\uE739"` in the *.cs instead of `"\xE739"` and it works fine.